# PHP/jquery/ajax loading small php script within a set interval

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have my main file which is displaying some graphs etc - this works fine.

Now I came up with the idea to display some temperatures in a more timely fashion - as in - refresh it every like 2 - 10s.

Ive added a little php script which explodes the sensor info and formats it, this works fine by itself:

```
$sensor1 = file_get_contents('sensor1');
$sensorinfo1 = explode ("t=", $sensor1);

$sensor2 = file_get_contents('sensor2');
$sensorinfo2 = explode ("t=", $sensor2);

printf("Aktuelle Temperaturen:  Sensor1: %s  Sensor2: %s", $sensorinfo1[1] / 1000,$sensorinfo2[1] / 1000);
```

My knowledge about Javascript, Ajax and jQuery is rather ... well. Lets not talk about it.
I came up with the following things for that part after searching around for a while already (it doesnt work, and I do not know why):

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('#curtemp').load('grabsensorinfo.php', function () {
        }, 5000);
});
```

and the div element:

```
<div class="curtemp">
</div>
```

So what I'd like to have is the div element being updated every X seconds..
Anyone got an idea where I go wrong?

This is what I got to now - not working still:

```
var tempUpdate=function() {
    $('#curtemp').load('grabsensorinfo.php')
    };   
setInterval(tempUpdate,5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the function without the `()`, this way:

```
var callme=function () {
      $('#curtemp').load('grabsensorinfo.php');
    };
```

EDIT: you don't need to pass an empty function when calling `load()` , just call it with the page address as an URL. Try it inside Chrome of Firefox console to check that it works correctly

then (after loading the page as suggested):

`$(function(){setInterval(callme,5000);});`

otherwise, JavaScript will call the function once at the beginning, and then *call the returned value*.

It seems strange, let's say that now you are saying "*please, call the returned value of this function every 5000 ms*", not "*call this function every 5000 ms*".

Comment: shouldn't it be set on ready? otherwise there might be a problem if jQuery was delayed in loading...

Comment: It doesnt seem to work. This is the code im trying now:
    var tempUpdate=function() {

        $('#curtemp').load('grabsensorinfo.php')

     };   

    setInterval(tempUpdate,5000);


damn editing ......

Comment: code edited as suggested by Moak, try it now. Also, have you checked using the console that the resource you want to load is correctly returned?

Comment: Im trying it now! The php script works by itself when I call it seperatly.